# Project Euler problem 54 wrong answer. Probably doing something very wrong

Tags: clojure

I was trying to solve problem 54 in project Euler. https://projecteuler.net/problem=54

I am getting a wrong answer (378). Any ideas for me to explore are welcome. I've wasted quite a bit of time on this and now I'm stuck.

General code improvement suggestions are also welcome (even though this is not code review).

```
(defn consecutive? [nums]
  (->> (sort nums)
       (reduce #(vector (conj (first %1) (- %2 (second %1))) %2)
               [[] (dec (first nums))])
       (first)
       (apply =)))

(defn card-order-greater [c1 c2]
  (> (first c1) (first c2)))

(defn same-suit? [cards]
  (apply = (map second cards)))

(defn royal-flush? [hand]
       (and (same-suit? hand)
            (= (ffirst hand) 10)
            (consecutive? (map first hand))
            (sort card-order-greater hand)))

; (royal-flush? [[10 :H] [11 :H] [12 :H] [13 :H] [14 :H]])
; (royal-flush? [[9 :H] [10 :H] [11 :H] [12 :H] [13 :H]])

(defn straight-flush? [hand]
  (and (same-suit? hand)
       (consecutive? (map first hand))
       (sort card-order-greater hand)))

; (straight-flush? [[10 :H] [11 :H] [12 :H] [13 :H] [14 :H]])
; (straight-flush? [[9 :H] [10 :H] [11 :H] [12 :H] [13 :H]])
; (straight-flush? [[8 :H] [10 :H] [11 :H] [12 :H] [13 :H]])

(defn are-all-equal-nums? [subhand]
  (apply = (map first subhand)))

(defn add-other-cards [hand subset]
  (concat (apply vector subset) (sort card-order-greater (cs/difference (set hand) (set subset)))))

(defn four-of-a-kind? [hand]
  (let [foak (->> (combo/combinations hand 4)
                  (filter are-all-equal-nums?)
                  (first))]
       (when foak
             (add-other-cards hand foak))))

; (four-of-a-kind? [[10 :H] [11 :H] [12 :H] [13 :H] [14 :H]])
; (four-of-a-kind? [[12 :H] [10 :H] [10 :S] [10 :D] [10 :C]])

(defn split-to-two-and-three [hand]
  (->> (combo/combinations hand 2)
       (map #(list % (vec (cs/difference (set hand) (set %)))))))

; (split-to-two-and-three [[10 :H] [11 :H] [12 :H] [13 :H] [14 :H]])

(defn full-house? [hand]
  (let [fh (->> (split-to-two-and-three hand)
                (filter #(every? are-all-equal-nums? %))
                (first))]
       (when fh
             (apply concat (reverse fh)))))

; (full-house? [[12 :H] [12 :S] [10 :S] [10 :D] [10 :C]])
; (full-house? [[12 :H] [12 :S] [9 :S] [10 :D] [10 :C]])
; (full-house? [[10 :H] [12 :S] [12 :S] [10 :D] [10 :C]])
; (full-house? [[10 :H] [12 :S] [9 :S] [5 :D] [10 :C]])

(defn flush? [hand]
  (and (same-suit? hand)
       (sort card-order-greater hand)))

; (flush? [[8 :H] [11 :H] [6 :H] [13 :H] [14 :H]])
; (flush? [[10 :H] [11 :S] [12 :H] [13 :H] [14 :H]])

(defn straight? [hand]
  (and (consecutive? (map first hand))
       (sort card-order-greater hand)))

; (straight? [[10 :H] [11 :H] [12 :H] [13 :H] [14 :H]])
; (straight? [[10 :H] [10 :S] [12 :H] [13 :H] [14 :H]])

(defn three-of-a-kind? [hand]
  (let [toak (->> (split-to-two-and-three hand)
                  (map second)
                  (filter are-all-equal-nums?)
                  (first))]
       (when toak
             (add-other-cards hand toak))))

; (three-of-a-kind? [[10 :H] [10 :S] [12 :D] [10 :C] [14 :H]])
; (three-of-a-kind? [[10 :H] [10 :S] [12 :H] [13 :H] [14 :H]])

(defn two-pairs? [hand]
  (let [splits (->> (split-to-two-and-three hand)
                    (filter #(and (are-all-equal-nums? (first %))
                                  (->> (combo/combinations (second %) 2)
                                       (map are-all-equal-nums?)
                                       (some true?))))
                    (first))
        tp (when splits
             (vector (first splits)
                     (first (filter are-all-equal-nums? (combo/combinations (second splits) 2)))))]
       (when tp
         (->> tp
              (apply concat)
              (sort card-order-greater)
              (add-other-cards hand)))))

; (two-pairs? [[10 :H] [10 :S] [12 :D] [9 :C] [14 :H]])
; (two-pairs? [[10 :H] [10 :S] [12 :H] [14 :H] [14 :C]])

(defn one-pair? [hand]
  (let [op (->> (combo/combinations hand 2)
                (filter are-all-equal-nums?)
                (first))]
       (when op
             (add-other-cards hand op))))

; (one-pair? [[10 :H] [10 :S] [12 :D] [9 :C] [14 :H]])
; (one-pair? [[10 :H] [11 :S] [12 :H] [4 :H] [14 :C]])

;; Taken from internet
(defmacro cond-let
  "An implementation of cond-let that is as similar as possible to if-let. Takes multiple
  test-binding/then-form pairs and evalutes the form if the binding is true. Also supports
  :else in the place of test-binding and always evaluates the form in that case.

  Example:
   (cond-let [b (bar 1 2 3)] (println :bar b)
             [f (foo 3 4 5)] (println :foo f)
             [b (baz 6 7 8)] (println :baz b)
             :else           (println :no-luck))"
  [test-binding then-form & more]
  (let [test-binding (if (= :else test-binding) `[t# true] test-binding)
        else-form    (when (seq more) `(cond-let ~@more))]
    `(if-let ~test-binding
       ~then-form
       ~else-form)))

(defn hand-type [hand]
  (cond-let [rf (royal-flush? hand)] [9 rf]
            [sf (straight-flush? hand)] [8 sf]
            [foak (four-of-a-kind? hand)] [7 foak]
            [fh (full-house? hand)] [6 fh]
            [f (flush? hand)] [5 f]
            [s (straight? hand)] [4 s]
            [toak (three-of-a-kind? hand)] [3 toak]
            [tp (two-pairs? hand)] [2 tp]
            [op (one-pair? hand)] [1 op]
            :else [0 (sort card-order-greater hand)]))

(defn is-player1-winner-same-type? [det1 det2]
  (= 1
     (compare (apply vector (map first det1))
              (apply vector (map first det2)))))

(defn is-player1-winner? [hand1 hand2]
  (let [[res1 det1] (hand-type hand1)
        [res2 det2] (hand-type hand2)
        p1-winner (cond (= res1 res2) (is-player1-winner-same-type? det1 det2)
                        (> res1 res2) true
                        :else false)]
      p1-winner))

(defn p54 []
  (->> (str/split (slurp "p054_poker.txt") #"\s")
       (map (fn [s]
              (vector (nth s 0) (nth s 1))))
       (map (fn [[s-num s-suite]]
              (vector (case s-num
                        \2 2 \3 3 \4 4 \5 5 \6 6 \7 7 \8 8 \9 9 \T 10 \J 11 \Q 12 \K 13 \A 14)
                      (keyword (str s-suite)))))
       (partition 10)
       (map #(partition 5 %))
       (filter (fn [[hand1 hand2]]
                 (is-player1-winner? hand1 hand2)))
       count))
```

Comment: Test your `consecutive?` function.  E.g. `(straight? [[6 :S] [2 :C] [3 :H] [4 :S] [5 :S] ])` returns false.

Comment: Could you also paste in the output. You will get more attention if people can see the result without firing up an editor

Comment: @jas: You are correct. After fixing the `consecutive?` function, I get the correct answer. If you post your suggestion as an answer I can mark as solved. Thanks a lot for the catch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem appears to be in your `consecutive?` function. E.g., a call to

```
(straight? [[6 :S] [2 :C] [3 :H] [4 :S] [5 :S]])
```

returns `false`, though not if the cards are already sorted.

(It looks like you built little unit tests into your code and put them commented out, which is great. Unfortunately your tests for "true" straight and straight flush had the cards already sorted. It's good to think about a variety of cases --- one sorted, one random, and one sorted in reverse, for example.)

Otherwise, well done!